# No remote access to VPS container based on OpenVZ

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openvz

Is there any chance to start ssh server when sysinit is turned to DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=1?

I have no remote access at the moment to my VPS server (based on OpenVZ container), but I can edit files and reboot it through VDS manager. Every time I'm rebooting my VPS I can have SSH access only for few seconds then it hangs, so obviously some service is blocking SSH.

Is it maybe better to change back again to runlevel=2 and turn off every service except ssh? If yes, how to do it? I can edit files, but I can't upload or download anything.

Will I be able to recover this installation or not?

Comment: There should be some form of console available through the hardware node and exposed in the control panel, often as a serial console accessed using a Java application.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to level 3 and everything works fine after that. I couldn't figure out what happened and why it was on level 2. But I learnt something about sysinit.